# Difference between $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ and $f(x^2)=x$

Tags: functions

Is there a difference between $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ and $f(x^2)=x$ for $ x \in\mathbb R^+_ 0 $ ?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: hem, in $\mathbb R_0^+$, the are few $x<0$. ;)

Comment: @labbhattacharjee  These are real valued functions

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee it's written r+

Comment: There is no difference if you choose the domain as you have done, as the equation $y=x^2$ is equivalent to $x=\sqrt{y}$ for $x,y\ge 0$

Comment: No difference? What? Take a constant function $f$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference.

For $x>0$, you can always write $x=t^2$ with $t>0$. Then $f(x)=f(t^2)=\sqrt x=t.$

Answer (score 1):

Since $x$ is positive both functions are injective, there is no difference between the given functions.

Comment: this is not about injectivity, but about definedness.